# Can scrapy-splash Ignore 504 HTTP Status?

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

i want to scrap javascript loading web pages, so i use scrapy-splash but some pages   so lots of loading time.

like this :
[image]

i think [processUser..] things that makes slower.

there are any way to ignore that 504 pages ? because when i set timeout less than 90 , cause 504 gateway error in scrapy shell or spiders.

and can get result html code ( only get 200 ) when time i set is over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a mechanism in splash to abort a request before it starts loading the body which you can leverage using `splash:on_response_headers` [hook](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-on-response-headers). However in your case this hook will only be able to catch and abort the page when the status and the headers are in, and that is after it finishes waiting for the gateway timeout (504). So instead you might want `splash:on_request` [hook](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-on-request) to abort the request before it's even sent like so

```
function main(splash, args)
    splash:on_request(function(request)
        if request.url:find('processUser') then
            request:abort()
        end
    end)
    assert(splash:go(args.url))
    assert(splash:wait(.5))
    return {
        har = splash:har(),
    }
end
```

UPD: Another and perhaps a better way to go about this is to set `splash.resource_timeout` before any requests take place:

```
function main(splash, args)
    splash.resource_timeout = 3
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Splash to render a webpage you are basically using a web browser.

When you ask Splash to render http://example.com:

1. Splash goes to http://example.com
2. Splash executes all of the javascript
   2.1 javascript makes some requests
   2.2 some requests return 50x codes
3. Splash returns page data

Unforntunately Splash right now does not support any custom rules for blocking javascript requests - it just takes the page and does everything your browser would do without any addons: load everything without question.

All that being said it's highly unlikely that those 50x requests are slowing down your page load, if so it shouldn't be a significant amount.